# Laravel's artisan command takes over MySQL connections

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, digital-ocean

In Laravel 5.1, while we listen for the queue, all the other MySQL operations fail and I get the following error

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

I checked the MySQL status

```
Uptime: 629  Threads: 1  Questions: 166  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 694  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 400  Queries per second avg: 0.263
```

The server is hosted by DigitalOcean, spec is 512MB/1CPU.

What could the problem be?

Cheers

Comment: What is your max_connections configuration for MySQL?

Comment: its not set, in my.cnf

Comment: i have same error. by default it is 151. ideas why this happens?